# Canvas HTML5. Заливка и движение объекта

Tags: html5, canvas

https://youtu.be/SgQkKdQqUWo

Проблема с заливкой. На заднем плане оранжевый цвет. Как его убрать не пойму. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
public void drawSquare(CanvasPoint center, double dimension, CssColor fillColor) {
    context2d.beginPath();
    context2d.setFillStyle(fillColor);
    context2d.rect(center.x - dimension / 2, center.y - dimension / 2, dimension, dimension);
    context2d.fill();
    context2d.closePath();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение простое:

Надо открывать и закрывать path при рисовании каждого объекта.